How to retrieve Azure ADLS Gen2 Logs Using Rest API
I am looking for Azure Datalake Gen2 blob logs using REST API, currently I could see these logs can fetch when we enable Azure diagnostics setting like below.
Currently we have enabled diagnostics setting and as our datalake used heavily and generating 4 terabytes of data per day by azure monitor/diagnostics and this occurring around $ 30k per month under azure monitor meter in cost billing report.
So we are planning to turn off diagnostics setting and looking for any REST API can give similar information so we can fetch this data with minimal cost..

Much appreciated for your support and help on this. Please let me know if my ask is not clear.

It is not possible either you need to use azure diagnostics or azure storage logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging

To enable resource logs, you would need to have either of the below options turned on:
‘Diagnostic settings’ - enables Azure Monitor Logs
‘Diagnostic settings (classic)’ – enables classic logs
The first option try to export logs to a variety of destinations including to another Storage account, Log Analytics Workspace, etc. (exporting to Storage accounts is a cheaper option compared to exporting to Log Analytics Workspace which provides a richer query interface).
Which of these options are you using today (exporting to another
storage account)?
There are aspects like the log retention period
etc. which you can control/set to reduce overall logging costs.
Classic logs is the older approach (logs are sent to $log folder in the same storage account) which should be the cheapest; however, I want to call out that any new logging enhancements are targeted towards Azure Monitor Logs only. Given cost is the main consideration for you and log volume is high, perhaps have them evaluate classic logs for your  scenario.
